# Executing a stored procedure that returns a result set using sqlsvr_query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a function to get data out of an SQL Server 2008 database, the function so far is:

```
function searchMovements($cd,$nm) {

    $usr = $_SESSION['username']."A";
    $hashedpass = $_SESSION['hashedpass'];
    $svr = $GLOBALS["svrName"];
    $db = $GLOBALS["dbName"];

    $retarray = NULL;



    $qry = "EXEC dbo.UDEF_DCAPP_GET_BOOKINGS @STKCODE = ?, @STKNAME = ?";

    // echo("set query to ".$qry."<br>");

    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$db, "UID"=>$usr, "PWD"=>$hashedpass);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $svr, $connectionInfo);

    if ($conn == false) {

        sqlsrv_close($conn);
        // echo("Failed to connect");
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));


    } else {

        $params = array($cd,$nm);

        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qry,$params);

        var_dump($result);

        if($result == false) {
            sqlsrv_close($conn);
            echo("result empty");
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

            $retarray[] = $row;

        }

        sqlsrv_close($conn);
        return $retarray;

    }



}
```

---

The section I'm really having a problem with is:

```
$params = array($cd,$nm);

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qry,$params);

var_dump($result);

if($result == false) {
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    echo("result empty");
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
```

This section constantly returns `result empty`.

When I `var_dump` the `$result` variable I get `bool(false)`.

I have tried using a select statement instead, this seems to work fine.
I have run a trace on the SQL server, it runs the following query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.UDEF_DCAPP_GET_BOOKINGS @STKCODE = @P1, @STKNAME = @P2',N'@P1 varchar(8),@P2 varchar(max)','TESTCODE',''
```

Running this line from SSMS returns the results as I would expect.

The documentation seems to suggest this should work but is this a limit of the `sqlsvr_qry` function? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a few days, it was an issue with permissions.

When I was running the script in SSMS it was under admin privilege but PHP was running as the user.